# Android - launch closed application from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, launch

I want to launch my app from broadcast receiver, but my code only works, if the application is already open in the background. How can I launch the app, even if the app is closed? And is it possible to launch the app from BroadcastReceiver with another Activity than MainActivity?

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

       
            Intent startIntent = context .getPackageManager() .getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
            startIntent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED );
            context.startActivity(startIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not think this is possible. Maybe in the old android versions, where security was not paid much attention to. But with new android versions, esp. after Marshmallow, the background services were restricted in their working.

Comment: Thank you! Then I have to do it in a different way.